# Getting all posts that have the same tag of a post with Timber + Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, timber

As stated, I want to get_posts with an argument that includes tags.

For example this works:

```
$context['posts_tags'] = Timber::get_posts('category_name='.Timber::get_terms('category', array('parent' => 0)));
```

However, I want instead of `category_name` to have something like `tags_name`.

Then I want to render them like this:

```
{% for post in posts_tags %} 
    {% include ['tease-frontpage.twig'] %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Since the documentation is not enlightening at all, is there a way to do that?